# Mobile login with Oauth - keeping session stored in browser for web views

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using Xamarin Forms, IdentityServer (OpenID, OAuth2), and the IdentityModel.[OidcClient](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient) library for authentication. The mobile app is successfully logging the user in by opening an ASWebAuthenticationSession browser on iOS and a ChromeCustomTabsBrowser on Android. The user gets logged in and I store their access and refresh tokens to secure storage so I'm able to make API calls.

The issue I'm having is after the user logs in, I have places in the mobile app where I want to open a web view to web apps that are also secured behind IdentityServer. When I open the web view, the user is required to authenticate again.

Is there a way to prevent the user from having to log in again when opening web views after initial log in?

Comment: Forgive me if this seems like a bad question, but since you're storing the original auth, can you mock the second auth by presenting the original when the pages ask for it?

Comment: @PatrickGoode - sorry, I'm not following what you're describing.

Comment: Have you checked Gary Archer's answer?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I was able to solve this by using `SFSafariViewController ` instead of `ASWebAuthenticationSession`. I'll update this question with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve by using by using `SFSafariViewController` instead of `ASWebAuthenticationSession`. I use `SFSafariViewController` when logging in and then reuse that browser via dependency injection inside my app.

[Here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/issues/60#issuecomment-384891574) is comment describing how to use `SFSafariViewController`.

Comment: Congrats, could you please mark your reply as an answer so that others who have the similar question will get help from you? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before by implementing an authentication strategy in the web UI, based on the user agent:

- When the web UI is hosted in a full browser it uses browser based logins and silent token renewal
- When the web UI is hosted in a mobile web view it calls back the parent mobile app to get a token or trigger a mobile login

This enables the web UI to get and use a token from its mobile host, so that the user gets an integrated experience. T
he user gets mobile security + usability when running in a mobile context.

Technically you can implement an authentication interface with 2 implementations - along [these lines](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts).

It is tricky, but if done right you can isolate it to a few plumbing classes.

I will do a code sample and demonstrate this on my blog some time soon.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gary. I was able to solve by using `SFSafariViewController`.